# Handling arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, indexing

I'm just a beginner with C language.

I want to determine elements of array, but it failed.
I'd like to insert index(row=x, column=y). Is this possible?

Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

int main(void)
{
    int x, y;
    char coords[3][3] = { NULL };

    printf("x, y: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);


    coords[x][y] = 'O';




    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%c ", coords[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If x=2, y=2, I expect the outcome to be printed

```
␠␠␠
␠␠␠
␠␠O
```

(Where ␠ is a space)

I think `coords[x][y] = 'O';` is the problem, but i can't fix it.

Comment: Why do you think "\n" should be printed? Did you `printf("\\n")` anywhere? What does the code print as it is now? Your initialization is a bit strange, `NULL` is a value for a pointer. To initialize array elements to `0`, do `= { { 0 } };`. The "not explicitly initialized" array elements will be auto-initialized to 0.

Comment: https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/2d-arrays-in-c-example/

Comment: It is just a blank space :) I tried to show them.

Comment: `NULL` in `char coords[3][3] = { NULL };` makes no sense. On my compiler, it ends up populating the array with a NUL (character zero). There's absolutely no reason to believe it would populate it with spaces as you seem to expect!

Comment: The `sp` is a space? ; )

Comment: @KamilCuk, I put that in case someone has a problem reading the tiny "sp" or if they have a font that can't render the character.

Comment: Re your edit, Why do you print two character (`"%c "`) per array element if you just want one...

Comment: You cannot use `scanf` correctly unless you ***check the return***. E.g. `if (scanf("%d %d", &x, &y) != 2) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr; return 1; }` And **Enable Compiler Warnings** - for VS add `/W3` to your compiler options and do not accept code until it compiles without warning.

Comment: Regarding: `char coords[3][3] = { NULL };`   The array is of characters, but NULL is a pointer.  Perhaps you meant: `char coords[3][3] = { '\0' };`

Comment: regarding: `coords[x][y] = 'O';`   The valid range of `x` and of `y` is 0...2.  However, the code fails to verify those ranges in the values input from the user.  So the probability is the user entered 6, 7 ( or any (huge) number of other value pairs, all of which would result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not initialized your `coords` array as you perhaps think! The line:

```c
char coords[3][3] = { NULL };
```

actually gives all 9 elements the value of **zero** - which is the `nul` (unprintable) character. (If there are less initializers in the list than array elements, all 'extra' elements will be given the value of zero.)

What you perhaps want (to set all 9 elements to the blank space) is:

```c
char coords[3][3] = { {' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '} };
```

Or something similar, like using the `ASCII` value for the space (32) if you know your system uses `ASCII` encoding (which it is not *obliged* to).

Better would be to define your desired initial value as a constant, then use that as the initializer:

```c
const char X = ' ';
char coords[3][3] = { {X, X, X}, {X, X, X}, {X, X, X} };
```

as this makes it easier to change things (less typing) if you need to use a different initial character.

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
char coords[3][3] = { NULL };
```

The `NULL` makes little sense in here, although the compiler will most probably compile the code and initialize all elements to zero. Let's fix it to something more "correct":

```
char coords[3][3] = { { 0 } };
```

The array elements not initialized explicitly are initialized to `0`. For a reference, you could read [array initialization on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization).

Now we know that all out array elements are initialized with `0`. So you can check them before printing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (coords[i][j] == 0) {
            printf(" ");
        } else {
            printf("%c", coords[i][j]);
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Alternatively, you could initialize all array elements to `' '` character as suggested in the other answer.